# Having multiple contradictory options, how to handle them?

Tags: package-writing, package-options

Lets say you are writing a package, which has the usual pair of `draft` and `final`-mode.

But how should I handle, if this package gets the global option `final` and the local `draft`?

Consider the following ex.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{ex}[2014/07/26 v1.00 This is just an example]
\DeclareOption{draft}{\newcommand\@draftmode{true}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\let\@draftmode=\@undefined}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifdefined\@draftmode
  \newcommand\example{%
    an example text, only visible in draft mode}
\else
  \let\example=\relax
\fi
```

Using that in the following main.tex:

```
\documentclass[final]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{ex}
\begin{document}
some example text and eventually some more text: \example.
\end{document}
```

Results in the output “some example text and eventually some more text: .”. If I swap the `\DeclareOption` (`final` first, then `draft`), then at least I have the output of `\example`. But then it wouldn't work if I swap the options in the main.tex…

So what is the LaTeX way to handle this?

- Check if both options are set and then fire an error? (and how to check for both options?)
- Check if both options are set and then fire a warning?
- Prefer global option over local option? (how to check if a given option is global or local?)
- Prefer local option over global option?
- Just do it as I have and live with its problems? (how to decide which order might be more sens?)
- Use a package that I haven't found yet but really helps with such stuff?

Comment: From a user's perspective I'd expect that local options win

Comment: I think so too, but I really don't know how to check if an option was locally or globally set :(

Comment: There is a package ifdraft. With it you can test the class option. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my perspective as a user I expect that local options take precedence over global options if they contradict each other. If you want your package to behave like this then here's what I would do:

I would define a conditional, `\newif\ifex@draft`, say, and let the options either set this conditional to true or false:

```
\DeclareOption{draft}{\ex@drafttrue}
\DeclareOption{final}{\ex@draftfalse}
```

Then all that's left to do is to change `\ProcessOptions\relax` into `\ProcessOptions*`. The [`clsguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/clsguide) says about the starred version:

> This is like `\ProcessOptions` but it executes the options in the order
>   specified in the calling commands, rather than in the order of
>   declaration in the class or package. For a package this means that the
>   global options are processed first.

So a modified version of the example package could look like this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ex.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{ex}[2014/07/26 v0.0 This is just an example]
\newif\ifex@draft % implicitly false. Set to true if you want a different default behaviour

\DeclareOption{draft}{\ex@drafttrue}
\DeclareOption{final}{\ex@draftfalse}
\ProcessOptions*

\ifex@draft
  \newcommand*\example{Package `ex' in draft mode}
\else
  \newcommand*\example{Package `ex' in final mode}
\fi
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[final]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{ex}
\begin{document}
\example
\end{document}
```